# Remove all '\n' between '<' and '>' in C# with regexp

Tags: c#, html, regex

I need to remove all '\n' between '<' and '>' in html file with C#.

my code is below:

```
Regex.Replace(text, "(<[^<>)]*)\\n+([^><]*>$)", "\1\2");
```

But it obviously doesn't work. Any suggestions?

Example:

```
< style="



">
```

detailed example:

```
<td colspan="3" rowspan="2">
      <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="a10" cols="13" id="t_5" lang="en-AU">
       <tr id="t_5_FNHR">
        <td class="a26" style="HEIGHT:5.00mm">
         <div class="r11">LAKOTA - PINK PANTHER RETURNS-V</div>
        </td>
        <td class="a27" style="



">
         <div class="r11">5c</div>
        </td>
```

Another:

```
<td class="a34" style="



">
             <div class="r11">7,390.62</div>
            </td>
            <td class="a35" style="



">
             <div class="r11">617.81</div>
            </td>
            <td class="a36" style="



">
```

Comment: Wow, what on earth are newlines doing there of all places? :/

Comment: do you need to do this all the time? Or just once?

Comment: is the first close-paren in the regex supposed to be there?

Comment: These newlines are generated after we decode .mhtml to html. I need to format them so that I can compare to those generated earlier which have no newlines in between.

Comment: I need to do this once in my code. Then I will write the stream to a file and do comparing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An easy but obviously brittle way would be to remove all linebreaks where the next angle bracket is a `>`:

```
Regex.Replace(text, @"[\r\n]+(?=[^<>]*>)", "");
```

**Explanation:**

```
[\r\n]+  # Match one or more CR or LF characters
(?=      # if the following can be matched at the current position:
 [^<>]*  # any number of characters except angle brackets
 >       # and one closing angle bracket
)        # (End of lookahead).
```

Might be good enough for your case (if it isn't, regex probably is not the right tool anyway).

Comment: This almost works! However it removed 2 newlines and still left one new line between < and >. I hope it to be <something no new lines>.

Comment: <td class="a27" style="



">
             <div class="r11">5c</div>
            </td>
            <td class="a28" style="



">

Answer (score 0):

First create a regex that match a html tag, something like <[^>]+> and then use a match evaluator.

```
   Regex r = new Regex(pattern);
   var result = r.Replace(input, new MatchEvaluator(ReplaceNewline));

   public string ReplaceNewline(Match m)
   {
      return m.Value.Replace("\n", "");     
   }
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.matchevaluator.aspx